# How To Remove Leading Characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL 2012 which we can call 'Table' for instance. It has items like this in it,

```
Column

_one
_two
three_blah
four_blah
```

I would like to be able to do this,

```
select * from Table order by Column
```

And the result be this,

```
four_blah
one
three_blah
two
```

So it orders the items based on removing the leading underscore characters. It can't just blindly remove the underscore characters though because the underscores might be in the middle of the items.

For instance this does not work,

```
select Replace(Column, '_', '') from Table order by Replace(Column, '_', '')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming col caps out at 255 characters, this doesn't have to perform any checks on length or complicated case expressions:

```
SELECT col = SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', col), 255)
  FROM dbo.table
  ORDER BY col;
```

Updating to show an example that works with varchar even if the value I hard-coded exceeds the size of the column:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(col VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @t VALUES
('_one'),
('_two'),
('three_blah'),
('four_blah');

SELECT col = SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', col), 255)
  FROM @t
  ORDER BY col;
```

Results:

```
col
----------
four_blah
one
three_blah
two
```

---

Another alternative (that doesn't require hard-coding the length of the string or determining the length of every value in the table) is to use STUFF. Note that this does change how strings without a single alphabetic character will be handled (NULL output instead of being left alone). Those rows will still sort first, they'll just be less meaningful. You can deal with those however you like by adding `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT col = STUFF(col, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', col)-1, '')
  FROM @t
  ORDER BY col;
```

(This portion of the answer should be credited to [@MikaelEriksson](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2103/mikael-eriksson).)

Comment: This only works if the column is fixed length, it wont work on a VARCHAR for instance as you would get an error saying that you passed the end of the string... assuming the VARCHAR is less than the value you hard code that is :)

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone sorry but I don't think you're right. It will even handle cases where the string is just `_____` (but it will sort those first and not remove any of those characters).

Comment: Well I'll be... I retract my statement, it clearly works! Now it begs the question of should it...? :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand nice answer. never considered the possibility of **multiple** `_` preceding relevant data

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone why shouldn't it? It's a varchar. I can say DECLARE @x VARCHAR(400) = 'x' - do you expect 399 space characters? It's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Not quite, I expected that for anything of 255 or more it would work. But I also expected that if you declared a VARCHAR(32), using a length of 255 in the SUBSTRING puts you past the end of the string so logically (in all other languages) you get an "index out of range exception"... (+1 BTW) ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone that would be true perhaps if 255 were the *start* position, but not the *end* position.

Comment: Doesn't matter the size of the column. It works fine.

Comment: i think it won't work correctly for the string '+a' because this would resulkt in 'a'

Comment: @miracle173 perhaps, do you have information about the requirements that nobody else here has?

Comment: but the only two possibilities are '_a' or 'a' this is sufficient and solves my problem nicely. Doesn't have to be any more complicated than it is.

Comment: sorry, I overlooked that the table contains only the strings _one,_two,three_blah and four_blah

Answer (score 1):

The following is a little bit tricky but the only function I found that could replace a repeating character from the head of a string was the function LTRIM. I did not find any regular expression function (as found in other languages) that can do the work.

Instead of the other solutions currently presented it does the work for a varying number of leading underscores and for a string containing arbitrary characters.

col should be the name of the column. Then the following expression will contain a blank on each position where  col contains an underscore and the expression contains a non blank where col contains a non underscore (Of course another character instead of # except underscore and blank can be used to do the trick)

```
replace(replace(col,' ','#'),'_',' '))
```

Now I calculate the length of the desired string:

```
len(ltrim(replace(replace(col,' ','#'),'_',' '))))
```

Knowing the length of the desired string makes ist easy to calculate the desired string from col by using RIGHT

```
right(col,len(ltrim(replace(replace(col,' ','#'),'_',' ')))))
```

EDIT:

now I found another expression to do the job:

```
substring(col, PATINDEX('%[^_]%', col), len(col)) /* or optionally replace len(...) with 255 to keep consistent with other solutions in this post i.e. avoid using the len function and use a fixed constant instead */
```

E.g.

```
;WITH CTE ([Index], col1) AS (
  SELECT 1 AS [Index], NULL  AS col1 UNION
  SELECT 2 AS [Index], ''    AS col1 UNION
  SELECT 3 AS [Index], 'x'   AS col1 UNION
  SELECT 4 AS [Index], 'x_'  AS col1 UNION
  SELECT 5 AS [Index], '_x'  AS col1 UNION
  SELECT 6 AS [Index], '__x' AS col1
)
SELECT [Index], SUBSTRING(col1, PATINDEX('%[^_]%', col1), LEN(col1)) AS Result
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [Index]
```

Returns:

```
Index|Result
    1|NULL
    2|''
    3|'x'
    4|'x_'
    5|'x'
    6|'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select 
  case 
    when column like '_%' then substring(column, 2, len(column) - 1)
    else column
  end as value
from table
order by 1;
```

This is off the top of my head and so it is untested...

Comment: I think if there is more than one leading underscores this will not remove all leading underscores